# Automatically move focus to cell in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

Whenever you open a Google Sheet your focus is automatically in the A1 area. However, I've been using this sheet for a while and have to manually move to C2427 or so to see the stuff I'm actually working with.

Is there some code I can put somewhere to move the view like this? At least for the first time I open the sheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option might be simply to right click on C2427, and under 'View more cell actions' select 'Get link to this cell'. This copies a URL link to the clipboard which you can use to open the sheet with C2427 at the top-left of the screen and selected. This also works for ranges and named ranges.

Comment: I ended up using this answer, but the other one is probably closer to what I was originally asking for.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there some code I can put somewhere to move the view like this?

Yes.

To get started, take a look at [jumpToToday_](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/32097728?msgid=33126935).